# How to retrieve contact details from custom account?

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-syncadapter

I've created an android app with my custom account type.The account type shows in Accounts & Sync settings and all my contacts sync from own server to my phone works normally.

My code for adding a contact to custom account.

```
private static void addContact(Account account, String name, String username) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Adding contact: " + name);
    ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> operationList = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

    ContentProviderOperation.Builder builder = ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI);
    builder.withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, account.name);
    builder.withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, account.type);
    builder.withValue(RawContacts.SYNC1, username);
    operationList.add(builder.build());

    builder = ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI);
    builder.withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0);
    builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
    builder.withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, name);
    operationList.add(builder.build());

    builder = ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI);
    builder.withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0);
    builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, "vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.com.example.mysync.profile");
    builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.DATA1, username);
    builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.DATA2, "SyncProviderDemo Profile");
    builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.DATA3, "View profile");
    operationList.add(builder.build());

    try {
        mContentResolver.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, operationList);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

How to retrieve new contact information(name,phone etc) inserted
    by [EditSchema](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.0.3_r1/packages/apps/Contacts/tests/res/xml/test_basic_contacts.xml). 
I want to get the my custom account contact details only, not all contacts.